# How to open speific tab from passing Intent in android?

Tags: android

I have a activity call "Wallet" in which there in implementation of switch case in and having another activity that contain tablayout in which 1st tab named as "Mobile" and 2nd tab named as "Data".what I want from activity "Wallet" switch case in case0: i am passing Intent to another activity that contain tablayout want to open tab "Mobile" and on case 1: Intent want to open tab "Data".How can I do that please tell me.

code for Wallet switch:-

```
m_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent mMobileRecharges = new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CRechargeMain.class);
                    startActivity(mMobileRecharges);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent mDataRecharge = new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CRechargeMain.class);
                    startActivity(mDataRecharge);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent m_Earning= new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CWalletTransactionScreen.class);
                    startActivity(m_Earning);
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```

and code for TablayOut Activity :-

```
public class CRechargeMain extends AppCompatActivity {
View m_Main;
private ViewPager m_ViewPager;
private Toolbar m_ToolBar;
private String[]actonBar={"Mobile Recharge","Mobile Data Recharge"};
int iDoWhat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recharge_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    init();
}

public void init() {
    m_ToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(m_ToolBar);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    m_ToolBar.setTitle("Mobile Recharge");

    TabLayout m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Mobile"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Data Card"));// add stories tab
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab

    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    CRechargePager m_oMobilePager = new CRechargePager
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oMobilePager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            m_ToolBar.setTitle(actonBar[tab.getPosition()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wallet, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following your example

```
m_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent mMobileRecharges = new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CRechargeMain.class);
                    mMobileRecharges.putExtra("tab_position",0);
                    startActivity(mMobileRecharges);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent mDataRecharge = new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CRechargeMain.class);
                    mDataRecharge.putExtra("tab_position",1);
                    startActivity(mDataRecharge);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent m_Earning= new Intent(CMyWalletScreen.this,CWalletTransactionScreen.class);
                    startActivity(m_Earning);
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```

// CRechargeMain Activity 
Add one line in your code
m_TabLayout.getTabAt(getIntent().getIntExtra("tab_position", 0)).select()

```
public class CRechargeMain extends AppCompatActivity {
View m_Main;
private ViewPager m_ViewPager;
private Toolbar m_ToolBar;
private String[]actonBar={"Mobile Recharge","Mobile Data Recharge"};
int iDoWhat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recharge_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    init();


}

public void init() {
    m_ToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(m_ToolBar);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    m_ToolBar.setTitle("Mobile Recharge");

    TabLayout m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Mobile"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Data Card"));// add stories tab
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab

    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    CRechargePager m_oMobilePager = new CRechargePager
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oMobilePager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            m_ToolBar.setTitle(actonBar[tab.getPosition()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

// Add this line in your code

    m_TabLayout.getTabAt(getIntent().getIntExtra("tab_position", 0)).select();



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wallet, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Wallet Activity pass 0/1 from intent.

In CRechargeMain Just add following code.

```
//here tab index 0 or 1
m_TabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

Comment: give me sample hint

Comment: please check my new answer i have added  new code lines in your code